# Stripe adding paymentMethod to trial subscription and later validate credit card

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-method

I'm working on stripe integration with react node.js

While creating a subscription without trial, I have no issues, and all use-cases are much simple.

But, I'm trying to create free trial without collecting credit card details, later when trial expired, I would like to collect credit card details

Server side: Creating  Trial Subscription without payment method:

```
  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{ price: priceId }],
    trial_end: expiredAt.unix(),
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'], 
  });
```

ClientSide: Later when trial expired, I would like to collect credit card details(paymentMethod), check if user action is required due to failures or 3ds and update the subscription by updating the customer's default payment_method:

```
  const updateCustomerDefaultPaymentMethod = await stripe.customers.update(
    customerId,
    {
      invoice_settings: {
        default_payment_method: req.body.paymentMethodId,
      },
    }
  );
```

How can I update the subscription to perform paymentIntent or charge the user, and return to client same subscription object with status 'in_complete' same as when creating subscription without trial_period?
Currently when running my code, I keep getting status='active' because the first invoice is in status='paid' with price of '0$'.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of a free trial, creating a subscription won't result in an initial payment, and Stripe will instead create a [SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents) under the hood for you automatically. This SetupIntent is meant to be used when collecting the customer's payment method. So at [any point during the trial](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.trial_will_end), the customer would need to return to your app to enter their credit card details, which you would then save using the SetupIntent:

- [subscription.pending_setup_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent)
- [Confirm the SetupIntent with the collected card details](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#confirm-the-setupintent)

Once the payment method is setup and saved to the customer (as the [default payment method for invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method)) it will be used to pay for the subscription's first invoice when the trial ends. The [first payment *after a trial* is considered an off-session payment](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#faq) (last FAQ), so if that payment fails Stripe will attempt to recollect the payment using the usual [smart retries and dunning](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/automatic-collection) functionality.

In a nutshell, you need to use the SetupIntent that's created (and attached to the subscription) to save the user's payment information.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid/restrict starting a trial subscription without payment details?